# What are the common arguments against theistic evolution?

Tags: genesis, young-earth-creation, evolution, theistic-evolution

What are the common arguments from Christians against the idea that God used evolution to create Earth over millions of years? This is not a place to argue. I'm interested in a rundown of the common response from Young Earth Creationists. Source your statements whenever possible.

Comment: Can you define your concepts better in the question? I am not familiar with these terms. It sounds like "Old Earthers" could represent a group of people with a range of views according to Wikipedia. Which specific beliefs do you you have questions about?

Comment: Is this better?

Answer (score 4):

The first would be the lack of death prior to the Fall - as recorded in the creation account in [Genesis 1-2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NASB&search=Genesis%201-2): God's creation was "very good", and death was a result of the curse on Adam for sinning ([Genesis 3:17-19](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%203:17-19&version=NASB)).

If the written account of the Fall is correct (which I would argue it *must* be for Paul's profuse arguments through Romans (eg [5:12](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%205:12&version=NASB) "Therefore, just as through one man sin entered into the world, and death through sin, and so death spread to all men, because all sinned") to be sound), then "evolution", as commonly understood with a molecules-to-man transformation, cannot be right.

[Romans 8:19-22](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%208:19-22&version=NASB):

> For the anxious longing of the creation waits eagerly for the revealing of the sons of God. For the creation was subjected to futility, not willingly, but because of Him who subjected it, in hope that the creation itself also will be set free from its slavery to corruption into the freedom of the glory of the children of God. For we know that the whole creation groans and suffers the pains of childbirth together until now.